# Angular import module performance

Tags: angular

Let's say I have a shared module that exports others modules.

```
class SharedModule {
  exports: [ ... ]
}
```

If in another module I need only one module that the `SharedModule` exports, regarding performance there is a difference if I include only this **one** module or the `SharedModule`?

```
class OtherModule {
  imports: [SharedModule or OneModule]
}
```